# How to compare two lists and insert values based on one into the other by a property in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am new to kotlin and I am trying to loop through two list and insert email in people.

```
data class User(val id:String,val name: String,val email: String)
data class Person(val id:String,val name: String, val email: String="")

//Input
val users = listOf(User("1","John","john@a.com"),User("2","Doe","Doe@a.com"))
val people = listOf(Person("1","John"),Person("2","Doe"))


//expected
val userToPerson =  listOf(Person("1","John","john@a.com"),Person("2","Doe","Doe@a.com"))
```

I am trying with this.

```
      
        val map = people.map { it ->
            {
                val foundUser = users.find { user -> user.id == it.id }
                if (foundUser != null) {
                    it.email = foundUser.email
                }
            }
        }
        map.forEach(System.out::print)
```

I am getting error for `foundUser.isNotNull()` here `Unresolved reference: isNotNull`

Updated with suggested:

```
() -> kotlin.Unit() -> kotlin.Unit
```

I am trying to convert a list of `users` to a list of `people`. They both have their `id`s as common.

I want to update people `Person` class corresponding to their user email.

All people do not have email. But all users have the email.

So, the final result would have people with email. If there is a person with no matching id, we can skip that data.

Comment: Why not just do `foundUser != null`?

Comment: Could you explain in words the end result you want, in general terms? (That's always a good place to start; it can avoid getting bogged down by irrelevant details.) In particular, do want to update your `people` list in-place, or create a new list? (Or both?) What if there's a Person in `people` with no corresponding User in `users`? Or vice versa?

Comment: `Person`.`email` is immutable (a `val`), so it can't be updated. Did you mean to make it a `var`, or do you want to create new `Person` objects with the updated email address?

Comment: Oh since, its immutable. I can make a new object and what option do I have if i go with var?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, calling `find` for every person is not only a bit awkward to write, it's also (which is far worse) inefficient. (It takes time proportional to the *square* of the number of people, which means it will perform *really* badly as the number of people gets large.)

To fix that, I'd create a *map* from an ID to its `User`:

```
val usersById = users.associateBy{ it.id }
```

We can then look up users by their ID quickly, in a way which scales well.

Armed with that, the solution can be fairly straightforward. Here's one which creates new* `Person` objects:

```
val userToPerson = people.map{ person ->
    val user = usersById[person.id]
    if (user != null && user.email != person.email)
        Person(person.id, person.name, user.email)
    else
        person
}
```

This solution is a little longer than necessary, but I hope it's easy to read and understand. It also avoids creating `Person` objects unless necessary, for efficiency. And when there's no corresponding `User`, it uses the existing `Person`.

---

* As the question is currently written, `Person`'s fields are immutable, so the existing `Person` objects can't be updated with a new email address. That leads naturally into a [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) style.

That's not necessarily a bad thing; immutability has many benefits, such as being easier to think about, and thread safety. It can also allow some compiler optimisations. However, if you're not careful, it can generate lots of temporary objects, which can can reduce efficiency (due to cache misses, constructor calls, and then more frequent garbage collections).

The alternative would be to make `Person` mutable, and do all the updates in-place — which is the traditional [imperative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming) style that most of us started from.

Both approaches are valid; which one you choose is a trade-off involving safety, maintainability, and performance — Kotlin supports both.